# Calculate mean every 5 rows specific column and select last data (fifth) of another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas df with say, 100 rows, 4 columns. I want to calculate mean in specific columns("Value") every 5 rows and select last data(Fifth) of another column("Date") to keep in new dataframe. How can I do that?

My dataframe that looks like this :

```
>>df
          Date     Product     Location       Value
0   12-08-2018           A           S1       1.313
1   12-08-2018           B           S1       3.089
2   12-08-2018           C           S1       1.890
3   12-08-2018           D           S1       3.136
4*  12-08-2018           E           S1       3.258
5   13-08-2018           F           S1       3.113
6   13-08-2018           G           S1       2.651
7   13-08-2018           H           S1       2.135
8   13-08-2018           I           S1       1.555
9*  14-08-2018           J           S1       2.009
10  14-08-2018           K           S1       1.757
11  14-08-2018           L           S1       1.808
12  14-08-2018           M           S1       1.511
13  15-08-2018           N           S1       2.265
14* 15-08-2018           O           S1       2.356
```

and I would like to turn it into new dataframe looks like this :

```
>> new_df
      Date           Value
0  12-08-2018       2.5372
1  14-08-2018       2.2926
2  15-08-2018       1.9394
```

Can you help me out?

**Note : I add * for easy to observe at every 5 rows.**

Comment: Sorry sir. @Harsh Patel. I'm beginner user of stack overflow and my English language skills're weak. I use google translate to help me. I'll be your guided to improve myself. I'm Thai people. If you know video tutorial to use stackoverflow for ask any question or answer. Can you put link at here?  Thank you so much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and `mean` with `np.arange` with floor division by `5`:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 5).agg({'Date':'last', 'Value':'mean'})
print (df)
         Date   Value
0  12-08-2018  2.5372
1  14-08-2018  2.2926
2  15-08-2018  1.9394
```

If default `RangeIndex` solution should be simplify:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index // 5).agg({'Date':'last', 'Value':'mean'})
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.arange(len(df)) // 5)
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help me. But result is switch column. 
new_df first column's "Value" and second column's "Date" .
How switch column back??

Comment: @kanpiseksasuk - You can use `df = df[['Date','Value']]`

Comment: Is there another way? Because I have too many array and row in my code.

Comment: @kanpiseksasuk - You can pass `Orderdict` to `agg` like `OrderedDict([('Date', 'last'), ('Value', 'mean')])`,  check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns)

Comment: I just noticed that my data is average every 5 rows but last data that have 1,2,3,4 rows it was average with same. I would like my data average every 5 row. If it isn't 5 rows, don't average. Do you have a way to do this?

Comment: @kanpiseksasuk - Not easy, is possible create new question?

Comment: Sorry sir, I don't understand. I'm beginner user of stack overflow. 
Would you like that I create question in new post or change question

Comment: @kanpiseksasuk - Here is best create new question, is possible it for you?